# Template deduction on function with variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a sort of task graph. When I emplace new Tasks I want to be able to add a varying amount at once and get a tuple that contains a handle for each added task.

I have written a base case for one task and overload with variadic template arguments that calls the base case.

```
template<typename Task>
node<Task> emplace(Task&& task) {
  return node<Task>{std::move(task)};
}

template <typename... Tasks, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Tasks) > 1)>>
auto emplace(Tasks&&... tasks) {
  return std::make_tuple(emplace(std::forward<Tasks>(tasks))...);
}
```

When I now emplace with one task like

```
emplace([](){ something cool; });
```

I get no error but when I add two or more tasks

```
emplace(
  [](){ task a; },
  [](){ task b; }
);
```

I get an error saying that `template argument deduction/substitution failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Tasks) > 1)>` is just `void` (when it exists). So your template is `template <typename... Tasks, void> whatever`. So you have a non-type template parameter of type `void`. Good luck matching it.

What you actually want instead is `typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Tasks) > 1)>`, a type template parameter with a default value which may or may not be SFINAEd out.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Tasks) > 1), bool> = true` is a better replacement for `std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Tasks) > 1)>` than `typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Tasks) > 1)>`.  It handles overload corner cases better.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont not sure which corner cases you mean, could you explain?

Comment: @n-1-8 In cases where there are more than 2 candidates overloads you are using SFINAE on, yours results in a collision (both have a `typename` field, one with an invalid default), while the NTTI doesn't (only one has a `bool` NTTI field)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont hmm what if the other one has a non-type bool parameter?

Comment: @Yakk - AdamNevraumont Thanks, your suggestions worked. If you would post it as a answer and maybe add some explanation, I could mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. If both are doing SFINAE in the same way, only the one that passes the SFINAE test has a NTTP of type `bool`.  In theory you could have one doing SFINAE and another overload taking a `bool` and not doing any SFINAE that would conflict; I have never seen that happen.